# Number of Permutations on a Test

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

I've just recently learned about permutations and combinations, but a thought came up to me and it might just be my brain not being particularly as bright as it usually is, but how would I go about finding out the number of different ways  that one can fill out a test (in terms of answers)? For example, let's say that there's a 20 question test, and a person can answer each question with either A, B, C, or D. How many combinations of answers are there? Would I do $\frac{20!}{(20-5)!}$ (permutation), $\frac{20!}{5!(20-5)!}$ (combination, which I don't think is correct, but you never know), or something like $4^{20}$?

Help would be very much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: I highly discourage thinking of questions as strictly "permutations questions" and "combinations questions."  It might be useful *at times* to do so, however most questions as you get further along past the most basic introductory questions will require the use of several techniques combined.  It is more important to learn *techniques* rather than formulas.  In this case, this can be solved using the [rule of product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_product) and will indeed have an answer of $4^{20}$.

Comment: To see this, recognize that such a test could be described as a function from $\{1,2,3,\dots,20\}$ to the set $\{A,B,C,D\}$.  Picking the answer for question $1$ has four options, picking the answer for question $2$ again has four options, etc... multiplying the number of options available at each step yields the desired result.  Remember that the formula for permutations and combinations also come from applications of the rule of product.  E.g. $20\cdot 19\cdot 18\cdot 17$ describes the number of ways of choosing a "first" test question (20 options), a "second" (19 options), a third (18...)

Comment: The answer is $4^{20}$ provided that the person does not consider the option of omitting an answer, which introduces an extra choice for each question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way that I usually deal with permutations and combinations is by thinking about *where* the formulas come from in the first place.

For example, if you're interested in how many different pairs you can have out of the triple $A, B, C$, you're looking for all the *sets* of the form $\{x, y\}$. There are $3$ choices for $x$, and then $2$ choices for $y$. This gives us $3 \times 2 = 6$ potential pairings. But, we are dealing with sets, and we notice that $\{x, y\} = \{y, x\}$, so the counting about needs to be divided by two to account for the ordering of $x$ and $y$ not mattering. Hence the number of pairs is $6 / 2 = 3$, which you can verify by drawing them out. This corresponds to the formula
$$
\frac{3!}{2!(3-1)!} = \frac{3!}{2!} = 3
$$
which you know to be the "choose function".

This is the same if we were choosing sets of size three out of the four elements $A, B, C, D$. We are after sets of the form $\{x, y, z\}$, of which there are $4 \times 3 \times 2$ choices initially. But how many of them are the same? Well, the following sets are all equal:
$$
\{x, y, z\}, \{x, z, y\}, \{y, x, z\}, \{y, z, x\}, \{z, x, y\}, \{z, y, x\}.
$$
There is six sets that are all the same, which we note is the same as $3!$ (this is not a coincidence, convince yourself that this will always be the case with these set-like questions). Thus, the number of distinct sets that one can choose of size three out of four elements is
$$
\frac{4\times 3\times 2}{3!} = \frac{4!}{3!\cdot1!} = \frac{4!}{3!(4-3)!} = 4.
$$
Notice that again this is precisely the form of the choose function.

Now, what about your question? Well, assuming that an answer *must* be chosen, there are four choices for each question, and twenty questions. In the first question you have $4$ choices, in the second question you have $4$ choices, in the third question you have $4$ choices, ..., in the twentieth question you have $4$ choices, so you have
$$
4 \times 4 \times 4 \times \cdots \times 4 = 4^{20} 
$$
choices. In this case, there are no equivalent choices, so you don't need to divide by anything and you're done.